# ABS (Anti-lock Breaking System) light turns on in hot weather?

Tags: chevrolet, abs, aveo

For the last 3 summers in a row I have observed that my ABS light in the dashboard turns on during hot summer days. It gets in this sticky state where it does not turn off automatically on its own. Though sometimes turning off engine and starting it again seems to help.

However, for the last 3 winters I have never observed this ABS light glitch.

This makes me think it has to do something with the temperature. What could explain this?

I am living in California where roads don't get slippery. The only obvious difference between winter and summer to me seems to be temperature. Also when the light turns on I don't feel break pedal pumping so ABS probably is not kicking in. The car is 2007 Chevrolet Aveo with FWD.

Comment: Do you know the fault code that is raised?  Knowing this will probably answer your question.

Comment: I looked up the front impact air bag sensor online for it thinking it might be the same one as the one in my Chevy Silverado, but alas, it's different. These were a common problem for the 2004-early 2007 Silverados ... thought it might be the same for your Aveo. What @HandyHowie said is correct, the codes will help tremendously, but you'll need a code scanner which does ABS. Not every scanner can do that.

Comment: @HandyHowie I checked with OBD2 reader and there were no codes. Perhaps this was, because the ABS light was off at the time I got connected or my OBD2 reader is not capable to read ABS related codes (even in history logs).

Comment: As @Paulster2 says, common OBD2 readers only do basic engine functions, you may need to take it somewhere to read the codes.  Even though the light is off, it should still have a history of error codes stored.

Comment: @Paulster2 Do you know if such OBD2 readers available on Ebay or Amazon that could read ABS, Airbag and other "hidden" codes? What are the keywords to look for them? I remember that Chevrolet dealership last time charged me $250 just to read Airbag code without actually being able to pinpoint exact issue.

Comment: Check for an **ELM327 OBDII reader**. This is the part you plug into your port. These come in USB, Bluetooth, and WiFi versions. Then you need software which will read **SRS** (Supplemental Restraint System) and **ABS** (Anti-lock Braking System) codes. These usually come together as part of a bundle. Doing a cursory glance, though, I haven't found and which do more than read OBDII codes (they do this well). Personally I have an **INNOVA 3160d** reader which does both (as well as read OBDII codes).

Answer (score 0):

As everyone mention, some OBD2 scan tools also do ABS (and airbag and tpms and... I have one that controls the whole car including HVAC, power windows and horn - at least on a Chrysler product).  That will tell you right away what is causing the light.

On some cars, the ABS light comes on when there is a fault in the brakes themselves (low pressure front or rear).

This is not something to push off, get it diagnosed ASAP.